# NXLog TLS configuration

Tags: graylog, nxlog

I am trying to send logs using nxlog installed on a windows server to graylog server using TLS. I have created a self signed certificate.

My questions is, if I set AllowUntrusted value to True in nxlog configuration for om_ssl module, do I have to set the CAFile or CertFile values?

I was looking at their source code and this is what I found.

```
else if ( strcasecmp(curr->directive, "RequireCert") == 0 )
{
}
else if ( strcasecmp(curr->directive, "AllowUntrusted") == 0 )
{
}
```

Does this mean that the two properties and not used?

Answer (score 0):

> Does this mean that the two properties and not used?

No, you need to look a few lines further.